# JavaScript pop-up window with an error message in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am working on my first Rails App and now I came so far, that I need to integrate JS into my Rails App - in the view. Basically I wish to show a pop-up window, if the user doesn't fill out all the fields in the registration form. As I created my app with devise, I already have my _error_messages.html.erb as follows.

```
<% if resource.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>
      <%= I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                 count: resource.errors.count,
                 resource: resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)
       %>
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Basically in the form it just lists all the errors, meaning the fileds, which were not filled out. I tried to integrate the script directly in the document, but this didnt work.

```
 <script>
      function myFunction() {
        alert("I am an alert box!");
      }
 </script>
```

How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Add to your form `remote: true` attribute;

```
<%= form_for @model, remote: true do |f| %>
    your fields here
<% end %>
```

2. In your controller's action do something like this:

```
  def create
    @model = ::Model.new(model_params)
    if @model.save
      *your default successful code here*
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js do
          render template: 'model/failed_modal.js.erb',
                 layout: false,
                 locals: { error_messages: @modal.errors } // *or your way to send error messages to view template
        end
      end
    end
```

3. Create file named `failed_modal.js.erb` under the `views/model` directory (near other your views `new`, `create` etc.)
4. In your `new` view (or where your create form is located) place modal (popup or whatever you want to display to user). Something like this:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="modal-body">
      // errors will display here with javascript code
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

5. Add some styling to your modal (I found it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)):

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

6. Add ability to hide modal (and erase current errors) by clicking on the close icon or to the area around modal:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  var modalBody = document.querySelector(".modal-body");

  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    modalBody.innerHTML = "";
  };

  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
      modalBody.innerHTML = "";
    }
  };
});
```

7. And last but not least add js code you your empty `failed_modal.js.erb` to push errors to your modal (popup) window:

```
var errors = <%= error_messages.to_json.html_safe %>; //pass errors from controller action and read them in js

var errorForm = document.querySelector('#myModal'); //select our modal node;

Object.keys(errors).forEach(function(prop) {
  var modalBody = error_form.querySelector('.modal-body');
  var errElement = document.createElement('div');
  errElement.classList.add('alert');
  errElement.classList.add('alert-danger');
  errElement.innerText = prop + ':' + errors[prop][0];
  modalBody.appendChild(errElement)
}) // iterate through errors hash keys (object in js) to add them into modal body.

errorForm.style.display = "block";  // change display: none to display: block to show our modal with errors
```

By this time your errors will look ugly, like this: [image]

But I am sure you will handle this and customise it as you like.
Hope this will help you.

P.S. For point 6 you can put this code into new file, name it whatever you want and place in the `assets/javascripts` directory. By default your `application.js` should have `//= require_tree .` line which loads all your js files in this directory. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much. What I did, added a function to application.js which is like this:                  function myFunction() {
  alert("Please fill out all the required fields");
}                     and then just called this function in _error_messages.html.erb. like this             <% if resource.errors.any? %>
  <%= javascript_tag "myFunction()" %>
<% end %>.             It works, but I guess, it's a very-very bad way to do this. Right?

Comment: Well the main goal is to make it work, if it works - then you are doing it fine. Later, you will improve your coding style anyway. Good luck

Comment: Last question: in which file / where do I add the code, which you described in number 6 (Add ability to hide modal (and erase current errors) by clicking on the close icon or to the area around modal: )

Comment: I added p.s section to my answer, hope it will help you